# Android listener for HoloCircleSeekBar

Tags: android

I am using the Circle seek bar available here.
https://github.com/JesusM/HoloCircleSeekBar

I am trying to wire up my activity to respond to users moving the seek bar and have found this code in the seek bar class.

```
public void setOnSeekBarChangeListener(OnCircleSeekBarChangeListener l) {
    mOnCircleSeekBarChangeListener = l;
}

public interface OnCircleSeekBarChangeListener {
    void onProgressChanged(CircularSeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser);
}
```

unfortunately I don't know how to wire up my activity to respond to the listener.

in my activity onCreate I have a reference to the seek bar.

```
pb = (CircularSeekBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

But don't know where to go from there

the full class file is available here https://github.com/JesusM/HoloCircleSeekBar/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/jesusm/holocircleseekbar/lib/HoloCircleSeekBar.java

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working like so

```
pb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new CircularSeekBar.OnCircleSeekBarChangeListener() {

        public void onProgressChanged(CircularSeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // do your work.
            Log.d("CP", "progress="+progress);
        }
    });
```